# iOS: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section n

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am building an iOS app, basically the user create an item by pressing the "+" button and then the app should put the new item in according section of the table based on the location of the item. However I got the error: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update. Here is my code, thank you

```
let sections = ["Bathroom", "Bedroom", "Dining Room", "Garage", "Kitchen", "Living Room"]

@IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    /*
    //Make a new index path for the 0th section, last row
    let lastRow = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: 0)

    //insert this new row into the table
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)*/

    //Create a new item and add it to the store
    let newItem = itemStore.createItem()
    var Num: Int = 0

    if let index = itemStore.allItems.index(of: newItem) {
        switch newItem.room {
        case "Bathroom":
            Num = 0
            print("I am in here")
        case "Bedroom":
            Num = 1
        case "Dining Room":
            Num = 2
        case "Garage":
            Num = 3
        case "Kitchen":
            Num = 4
        case "Living Room":
            Num = 5
        default:
            Num = 0
            print("I am in Default")
        }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: Num)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return itemStore.allItems.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //create an instance of UITableViewCell, with default appearance
    //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")

    //get a new or recycled cell
    //if indexPath.row < itemStore.allItems.count {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

        //Set the text on the cell with the decription of the item
        //that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
        //will appear in on the table view
        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]

        if item.name == "" {
            cell.nameLabel.text = "Name"
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
        }

        if item.serialNumber == nil {
            cell.serialNumberLabel.text = "Serial Number"
        } else {
            cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber
        }
        cell.valueLabel.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"
        cell.roomLabel.text = item.room

        if item.valueInDollars < 50 {

            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor.green

        }else if item.valueInDollars >= 50 {

            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        }

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let LocationName = sections[section]
    return LocationName
}
```

thank you so much for your time!

and this is how I create item

```
 @discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
    let newItem = Item(random: false)

    allItems.append(newItem)

    return newItem
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should insert the item in the array first:

```
itemStore.allItems.append(newItem)
```

Also, there is a difference between sections and rows in `numberOfRowsInSection`(return number of rows for every section) you have a switch that returns the same number, it should be

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return itemStore.allItems.count
}
```

**Edit :**

The problem is when the table loads there is 0 rows for all the sections ( `itemStore.allItems.count` is zero ), when you try to insert a row say at section 0 , row 0 -- the dataSource must be updated only for that section , which is not happen in your case as it's the same array that is returned for all sections , so you must either have an array of array where inner array represent number of rows so addition/deletion from it doesn't affect other ones ,,,,, or lock the insert to say section 0 like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   if (section  == 0 ) { 
       return itemStore.allItems.count
   }
   return 0 
}
```

in this edit i inserted in 2 sections 0  and 2 with no crash because i handled `numberOfRowsInSection` to return old numbers for old section that why to be able to insert in all sections you must have a different data source array or manage from `numberOfRowsInSection`  , see edited demo here [Homepwner](http://www.mediafire.com/file/28fa6l4ja4tkmz9/Homepwner-Edited.rar)

Instead of setting footer in viewDidLoad implement this method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if(section == 5 ) {
        let textLabel = UILabel()
        textLabel.text = "No more Item"
        return textLabel
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: where do you add the line "itemStore.allItems.append(newItem)

Comment: before insertRows

Comment: I did it, the problem still exists

Comment: indexPath is [0,0]

Comment: if you are implementing the section logic , then you must have nested array not only one ???

Comment: createItem is inside itemStore ??

Comment: How to do do the nested array? Could you please show me your code? I am sorry I am a beginner and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, createItem is inside the itemStore

Comment: don't append it again before the insertRows , if you already append it inside the class

Comment: what do you mean by a demo?

Comment: i mean repository to github , so we can better find the problem

Comment: the problem is whenever i am trying to add a new item, the app crashes and gives me that error

Comment: under which category do you want the add to be ??

Comment: And I got another problem, after successfully adding the new item, the footer disappears, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Have a follow up question, let's say now I want to 1.allow moving the item between cells. 2. call a function to move a item from Bathroom to Bedroom. What should I do? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is something terribly wrong with your data source. Your `numberOfRow` for all sections is the same. i.e. **itemStore.allItems.count**. Which means you are setting the same number of rows in each section.
The main issue is, while adding a new item, you are inserting a new row in the specific section which means

> new number of rows for section = previous number of rows in section +
>   1

**However, there is no addition in the data source.**

So according to the code, you have inserted a new row, but your data source has one record less since you didn't add the item there.

So I would like you do the following in order of these steps :

> 1. Add item in required data source.
> 2. inserRowInSection

**Update** : **Remove the condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`** :

`if indexPath.section <= 1` **and it's else block**. You don't need that. If number of sections is less than 1, it won't be called. Moreover it's the **else** block which is getting called all the time because you already have sections in your code. So **if case** will never be called.

So I got the issue. In `itemStore.createItem()` the value for **room** is always **Room**. In the **switch-case**, you never have **Room case**. So it always falls in default case. You need to fix that.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, but i am new to iOS, could you please please please provide me the code for doing those two steps you list above. Thank you very much!

Comment: What does this line do : let newItem = itemStore.createItem()

Comment: Post the code in your question where you are creating an item.

Comment: I just post it up there

Comment: I had already removed it in my new code, the problem still exists

Comment: Share your code over dropbox or somewhere else. Make sure all your files exist in the shared code.

Comment: this problem is mainly at itemsViewController

Comment: the problem is whenever i am trying to add a new item, the app crashes and gives me that error

Comment: Check the updated answer. It's while creating a new item, the value for room property is always **Room** for which there is no case in switch-case

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i want because i am creating a new item and i want the user to give the new item a room name and then put that item in according section. So whenever I create it, because there is no room assigned, so i am just put it in the first section

Comment: Then you need to handle that in switch-case. As of now only default case is being called.

Comment: How do i handle it, i don't know the room the user assign to this newItem, so it only goes into the default case

Answer (score 0):

@Jacky.S I downloads your code and try to debug it.Fist look our error properly.

```
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0)
```

So It says before update, your `sections` has `0 rows`. Now you try to update you `tableview` using this piece of code.

```
print(indexPath)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

I just added the print statement for debugging purpose and it prints `[0, 0]` .So you say your tableview to `insert 0th row on section 0`.
Now when you insert any `row` into `tableview` it calls the `delegate` method.Now look at the below delegate method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
  section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        print("0",itemStore.allItems.count)
    }
    if section == 1{
        print("1",itemStore.allItems.count)
    }
   // print(itemStore.allItems)
        return itemStore.allItems.count
}
```

In your code you just `return` `itemStore.allItems.count`.I added the above code for debugging.Now look that `itemStore.allItems.count` always return 1.So for first `section` it works perfectly because few times ago you insert a `row` in first `section` whose index is [0 = row, 0 = section].So you previously returned `rows` for `section 0` is equal to the recently return `rows` for `section 0`.But When it comes for `section 1` you previously `return no row` that means your `section 1` has no `rows` in previous but in your above delegate method you also return `1 row` for section 1.Which is conflicting because in previous you never `update` or `return` any `rows` for section 1.That's why you code `crash` and and say that

> ```
> your number of rows contained in an existing section after the update is 1 which must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update. Which is 0.
> ```

So this is the explanation for you crash.

Now, to recover from crash your `allItems` should be a `dictionary` or an `array of array`.

```
var allItems = [[Item]]()
```

or

```
var allItems = ["String":[Item]]()
```

guess `allItems` element is something like this

```
allItems = ["bathroom":[item1, item2, item3],"bedroom":[item1, item2, item3, item4]]
```

so here you have 2 section one is `bathroom` and another is `bedroom`.First section have `3 row` and second one have `4 row` and in you tableview delegate method you have to `return 3` for `section 0` and `4` for `section 1`

Comment: I had fixed the problem, thank you. But i have another problem, how do you move the cell between sections

Comment: it's an another problem and you should ask different question.As you ask so in short flow [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T6yOrUJseE ]link.it may help you.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721656/ios-swift-4-uitableview-how-to-move-cells-among-sections], here is the link of the new question, thank you

Comment: page not found.give me the new questions link.I will try to answer it.Happy coding.